# The power $x^n$ in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $I=\left]-1,\ 1\right[$ be an interval, and $\left(I,\ \star\right)$ be a magma such that:

$$\left(\forall\  \left(x,\ y \right) \in I^2\right)\ x \star y=\frac{x+y}{1+xy}$$

I proved that $\left(I,\ \star\right)$ is an Abelian group (with $0$ as identity element).

My question: Is there any recurrence relation to calculate $x^n:=\underbrace{x\star x \star \cdots \star x}_{n \text{ times}}$?

I tried with $n=2$, and $n=3$, and I didn't find the relation.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is there a reason you suspect there's a nice way to express the nth power?

Comment: No, I'm not sure if there exist a "nice" formula of $x^n$.

Comment: At a glance, it's clear that the $n$th powers are all of the form $\frac{p(x)}{1+q(x)}$ for polynomials $p, q$. For low orders I calculated, it appears $p$ and $q$ differ in degree by $1$ and alternate  between which is of higher degree (with the minimum degree increasing by $1$ each time we operate by $x$). You could probably use this to set up an equation to solve for a recurrence relation, using unknown coefficients for $p, q$, but I don't see a clean way to solve it or prove any nice recurrence exists.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "$(I,\star)$ be a Magma"?

Comment: @ShyamalSayak Magma is a common name for an algebraic structure: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)

Comment: @sudeep5221  Your formula is incorrect. $\tan(\arctan(x)+\arctan(y))=\frac{x+y}{1\color{red}{−}xy}$. You need the hyperbolic tangent and its inverse to get the correct formula.

Comment: @jjagmath Oh right, of course. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With just a little effort one can calculate $x^4$, $x^5$ and the pattern emerge:

$$x^n = \frac{\binom{n}{1}x +\binom{n}{3}x^3 +\binom{n}{5}x^5+\cdots}{\binom{n}{0} +\binom{n}{2}x^2 +\binom{n}{4}x^4+\cdots}$$

and a straightforward induction prove it.